# QML memory leak when setting variable from C++

Tags: c++, qt, memory, memory-leaks, qml

I'm writing a QtQuick GUI on Windows 7 using VS2013 and trying to get a tool to draw a graph on a canvas.  The graph works just great until I try to set one of the canvas's properties that I defined.  When I do this the program produces a white window, the memory usage grows from a normal few hundred megs to a couple gigs and dies.

TimeLineGraph.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.0

Item
{
    id: timeLineGraphItem
    objectName: "timeLineGraphItem"

    width: 500
    height: 500

    Canvas
    {
        id: timeLineGraphCanvas
        objectName: "timeLineGraphCanvas"

        width: 500
        height: 500

        // The unitless scale of each tic
        property variant ticMeasures: [.1, .2, .5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 50, 100]

        // Current tic values for both X and Y axis
        property int xTicValue: 1
        property int yTicValue: 1
        property int axisLineWidth: 4
        property int ticLineWidth: 2
        property int ticLength: 300

        // The pixel height and width of the drawn graph
        property int graphHeight: 300;
        property int graphWidth: 300;

        // Where in the widget the 0,0 coordinate of the graph is
        property int graphXStart: 100;
        property int graphYStart: 400;

        property string title: "Default Title"
        property int minTitleSize: 6
        property int minLegendSize: 4
        property int minLabelSize: 4

        property variant ymaxs: [];
        property int maxValue: 100;
        property int numSeconds: 10;
        property int samplesPerSecond: 10;
        property int numSamples: numSeconds * samplesPerSecond;

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            xTicValue = ticValue(numSeconds);
            yTicValue = ticValue(maxValue);
        }

        //Timer
        //{
        //    id: timeLineGraphTimer;
        //    interval: 5;
        //    repeat: true;
        //    running: true;

        //    onTriggered: timeLineGraphCanvas.myupdate();
        //}

        function newDataReceived(newData)
        {
            console.log("got here 1 - ", newData);
            if(ymaxs.length > numSamples)
            {
                ymaxs.shift();
            }
            console.log("got here 2 - ", maxValue);

            maxValue = newData;

            if (maxValue == newData)
            {
                maxValue = newData;
                //yTicValue = ticValue(maxValue); //<-- Any of these two
                var value = ticValue(maxValue);   //<-- methods will kill
                yTicValue = value;                //<-- this program
                // ticValue(maxValue) //<-- Commenting the previous two
                                      //    lines and uncommenting this
                                      //    causes things to "run" great.
            }
            console.log("got here 3");

            ymaxs.push(newData);
            console.log("got here 4 : ", ymaxs[0]);

            requestPaint();
            console.log("got here 5");
        }

        function ticValue(maxValue)
        {
            var returnValue = 0;

            console.log("ticValue");
            for(var index = 0; index < ticMeasures.length; index++)
            {
                console.log("    ", index, " of ", ticMeasures.length);
                returnValue = maxValue / ticMeasures[index];
                console.log("    ", returnValue, " = ", maxValue, " / ", ticMeasures[index]);

                if((returnValue >= 5) && (returnValue <= 10))
                {
                    returnValue = ticMeasures[index];
                    break;
                }
            }

            console.log("end ticValue");
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
}
```

tempClass.cpp

```
#include "tempClass.h"
#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <iostream>

tempClass::tempClass(QObject* object)
{
    timeLineGraph = object;
}

void tempClass::onTimer()
{
    std::cout << "onTimer() 1" << std::endl;
    QMetaObject::invokeMethod(timeLineGraph, "newDataReceived", Qt::DirectConnection, Q_ARG(QVariant, QVariant::fromValue(5)));
    std::cout << "onTimer() 2" << std::endl;
}
```

tempClass.h

```
#ifndef TEMPCLASS
#define TEMPCLASS

#include <QtCore/QObject>

class tempClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    tempClass(QObject* object);

    public slots:
    void onTimer();

private:
    QObject* timeLineGraph;
};
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication apps(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));

    QObject* object = engine.rootObjects().value(0)->findChild<QObject*>("blargin")->findChild<QObject*>("timeLineGraphCanvas");

    object->setProperty("title", "new title");

    tempClass* tmp = new tempClass(object);

    QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
    timer->setInterval(100);
    timer->setSingleShot(false);
    timer->setTimerType(Qt::CoarseTimer);
    timer->start();

    QObject::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), tmp, SLOT(onTimer()));

    return apps.exec();
}
```

In the QML file, TimeLIneGraph.qml, in the function `newDataReceived(newData)`, I set the `yTicValue` variable based on the return value of the `ticValue(maxValue)` function.  This causes the program to memory leak and die.  However, if I simply call the function without setting `yTicValue` the program runs fine without the benefit of setting the tic values correctly and thus having a wonky looking graph.

I imagine that I'm invoking the function `newDataReceived` incorrectly but I'm confused.  As you can see I have some output statements to the console and I always every output that I expect to see.  In this regard the two surrounding the call in `tempClass::onTimer`.  Qt says to never set a QML object variable directly because it would not emit the correct signals.  That is the only warning I get about calling or changing things between QML and C++.

So, the question is, does anybody have any idea why setting the `yTicValue` variable causes the system to memory leak/use ten times more memory and then die?

Comment: Looks like a Qt bug, but you'd really need to minimize this first. Also, the connection type in `tempClass::onTimer()` shouldn't be forced to direct. If the target lives in the same thread as the timer, the automatic connection will act as a direct one. If they are not, you'd be in trouble without the automatic connection. So, *don't* force connection types unless you knowingly invoke thread-safe methods across thread boundaries. No method in a QML object is thread-safe, BTW.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for the tip about connections but this is neither a Qt bug nor a thread bug.  This is a simple case of over looking the most obvious thing.  See my answer below to conclude this exciting episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so after a bit of thought and getting my mind back into the Qt game I realized that the request to draw is a request, not a function call to actually paint.  The problem is technically a `divide by zero error`.  This, however, is something QML doesn't do.  Instead of dying horribly when you divide by zero the QML code simply returns `INF`.  So, when I was looping in the paint thread (not shown) I was going from one to `INF` and trying to draw an infinite number of lines.

So, I know you're wondering where I was getting zero.  Both `xTicValue` and `yTicValue` are assigned a value in the `ticMeasures` array.  Both properties are also integers.  So, when the `ticValue` function correctly returned a value of .5 the program would truncate that to zero.

So, lesson learned.  Don't take things like exceptions, asserts, and crashes for granted or you'll end up red faced like me.